# Run single application with vnc

Tags: 12.10, ssh, vnc

I would like to run an application on a remote ubuntu machine using vnc. Currently I have to

1. ssh into the remote machine and run x11vnc
2. Run vinagre locally
3. Start the application in the vinagre vnc window

How can I turn this into a single command line operation?  I can combine 1 and 2 into a bash script but how do I do 3 from the command line too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a specific app in your vnc session, you can use `vnc4server` and edit `.vnc/xstartup` to start your application. But the shared desktop won't be your physical X11 display, but another (virtual) display.

An alternative would be to use ssh / X11 forwarding (`ssh -X server`) : any graphical application you launch is redirected to your local desktop.

Comment: ssh/X11 forwarding is far too slow to be usable sadly for me.    I'll take a look at .vnc/startup, thanks.